# Caught UnicodeDecodeError while rendering: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xd0 in position 0: unexpected end of data

Tags: python, django, unicode, django-admin, syntax-error

Some day, when i wanted to enter django admin, i couldn't do this, because of this error. I dont remember what i've done, and dont notice, when this error start to appear..

here' full traceback: http://dpaste.com/418718/

Sorry for my english

Answer (score 2):

The database field is too small for the data in it, and silently truncated it on insertion. You'll need to repair the data by hand, and make the field larger as well.

Comment: Thanks! it worked for me! I was trying to use sqlite3 on development, now changed to mysql, and it works perfect!:)

Comment: Then increase the field size.

Comment: i found out the problem, in one of my models, in Meta class, i identified app_label='Аккаунты' in unicode, russian language, it was the problem..

Comment: You should be putting it in a unicode instead of a bytestring like that. http://farmdev.com/talks/unicode/

Answer (score 0):

I got this error when reading data from a Mysql table. The database had some fields in latin1 format.  Converting them to utf8 format helped.